# NGRX Component store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-component-store

Im new to Angular word (I personaly  prefer Vue), but we have to use it for our client.

Thing is, he recommended to use NGRX Component store and not global store or something else. And because project belongs to him, we need to code like he wants.

But, problem is, that my component stores are large. I mean, some of them have 500+ lines of code and one almost 1000. And thats too much, even 300 is.

Question is, is there any good practice to split large component store to smaller parts? Like services with its own "state" and logic and component store will just gather everything from them and share with components (but in this situation, you can directly inject service to needed component)

Thank you

Comment: you can use several stores for one component, or maybe create facade that depends on several component stores that is then injected into the component.
https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/smarter-not-harder-simplifying-your-application-with-ngrx-signal-store-and-custom-features/ here is an example how component store could be split into features in a factory way

Comment: I feel so sorry for you having to use ngrx in an environment that already ships reactivity and where you could just use regular JavaScript and vue.reactive. As for ngrx then yes - you should split your state into several stores for sure.

Comment: Thank you, I will try acording to article you provided.

Comment: Yeah Vue will be better, but I can get used to angular. What is worst, we are forced to 14.2 version because of UI library he is using. Sad we cant use newest v17